# Is this quantifier is true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

"Every mail message larger than one megabyte will be compressed".

Let $M(x) = x$ mail message 
$L(x) = x$ larger than one megabyte will be compressed

$ \forall x \space (M(x) \rightarrow  L(x))$

Comment: What you wrote says that every mail message is larger than one megabyte and will be compressed, which is different from what you want. Also you probably want e-mail instead of mail.

Comment: Thanks, @GitGud, I will edit appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You will need three predicate letters, not two.

Let:

- $M(x)$ stands for '*x* is a mail message'
- $L(x)$ stands for '*x* is larger than one megabyte'
- $C(x)$ stands for '*x* will be compressed'

Then we have that the sentence:

> "Every mail message larger than one megabyte will be compressed"

means that

> It holds generally that if *x* is a mail message and larger than one megabyte, then it will be compressed.

Now how to put it in adequate symbolism?